# Can a Google Static Map Display an Info Window?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api

Google static maps can display markers, images, polylines, etc but is there a way to display an info window? I'm not talking about a click event to show hide.. just simply have the static image include an info bubble.

[Google Static Map Ref.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/dev-guide)

[Example of image](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=13.0171749,80.2604959%7C13.0962573,80.2495762999999&size=400x400&markers=icon:https://ia601509.us.archive.org/18/items/pickup_20180122/pickup.png%7C13.0171749,80.2604959&markers=icon:https://archive.org/download/delivery_marker/delivery_marker.png%7C13.0962573,80.2495762999999&key=AIzaSyCloJwYPYL4Waex5N8asdKgx9tDhXS3IX8&path=color:0x2a5298FF%7Cweight:5%7Cenc:%7BlmnAezzhNpBfA%60CjA~Bj@f@Ht@BlBB%60IJbFDfDDFAPGLAvJHpAHlAYf@O%5CALFLNDFH%5EAHCRMb@OXyBaA_@IiAKaMMsC@qFEaNS_AMe@Ky@Yk@[uA%7B@cK%7DFgAeAUKo@k@cBgB_@_@a@[WMQEA]BMJM%60FPd@@EmAQqC?iARoAl@%7DCNkA@WEcBSgBWm@Ua@qCqDiEyFeDeEcB%7BBkEqGiDiFS_@cBqBOKeCu@wBq@cBi@%7B@_@uB%7B@a@Me@SoEqAuDw@cB]s@YCGmDgBQGOEm@AeCNqDLq@LY?s@IsB]mBWoFg@uA]cCw@[?iAQkCe@iB_@iA[eAS%7BAOuB]%7BMkA?@CBC@I@OGEGyDm@yAOEE%7DGm@%7BIm@yJq@oMcA%7BIy@iH%7D@_LuAcLsAeEi@iMcBwCe@aAOYBgBQuL_BkDc@YCk@CiHeA_QsCiCSYHe@Ho@AOCUIuDh@w@v@cAnAqC%60Dg@b@oA%7C@a@RoDvAmC%7C@s@ZILIXQN_Ab@%7D@p@%7DBdCu@Xa@Fc@@]Cq@Om@a@kAaAy@DQHMHJlDVfFH%7CBN%60B%5ErHp@nFUhCE%7C@@t@PfBVtBj@bERdAv@nBUBeDZoAHeDRkGh@_Hn@yCBSDg@NiAb@]PWJ[DuBE%7BIWc@?SBIBWPORMT?BCFKFOAkCAuBKWCOAEFEFe@l@]V%7DErBSH_@Ni@p@[Rq@~AYt@o@xBOp@aAzDcAbBeAxAi@v@u@hB%7B@zB%7B@zBd@H%5EB%5C?qA~Hg@dDWlC@%60DExAOlBI~BGjCBpAElCEvBO%7CCc@vJEr@Y%5EWZb@bANb@P%7C@nCBfDNE%60A@%60@B%5E).

Comment: The Static Map API is **static**.  If you want dynamic behavior use a different API or create the infowindow/click listeners yourself from clicks on the image.

Answer (score 1):

InfoWindow is not supported in the Static Maps API. That said, because a Static Map is just a standard image, you can use CSS rules to move a div into the desired position on the image to simulate a InfoWindow. Here is a simple example:

http://jsbin.com/foqozipiru/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    #info {
      background-color: white;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      border-radius: 10px;
      padding: 5px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 260px;
      top: 90px
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <img src=http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=600x400&center=37.796581,-122.404835&zoom=18&style=feature:poi|visibility:off&markers=icon:http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/red-circle.png|37.796581,-122.404835></img>
  <div id='info'>This is a div that simulates <br>an infoWindow </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Decent approach, but if the image is responsive the info window div moves away from the marker. Perhaps defining a custom maker image that mimics an info window during the static map request would be a better solution?

Comment: You could use the static image as a background, and `background-size:cover; background-position: center center;` and then have and infowindow always show precisely in the middle of the div. So it'd also be responsive.